# How to stop Shape recomputing already computed path over and over in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I got a simple Shape that makes a Circle Shape, this Shape does not take any parameters to work and just gives back the output, with those condition still MyShape calls its function for computing the path, how we can stop this over processing problem? if I have some more complicated path this action would cause to draw or compute the all complicated path with 1000 of 1000 lines or circles.

If you look at to the video, you can see that MyShape would called for resizing the window or just tapping on background which non of those actions have nothing to do with drawing method, I mean tapping on background or resizing the window are not input values for MyShape that we count them as condition changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            MyShape()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
                .background(Color.blue)
            
        }
        .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
        .padding()
    }
}

var callCount: Int = 0

struct MyShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        callCount += 1
        
        print("MyShape Called =", callCount)
        
        return Path { path in
            
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.width/2.0, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0.0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360.0), clockwise: true)

        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: SwiftUI redraw the scene when it feels like it. And by redrawing the scene it recreates your `MyShape` object calling the path method. And I don't think you can do anything about it. What you can try tho is to create the cgpath outside of the shape then feed it to your path to finally measure if there is a performance gain. The UI will always redraw when SwiftUI wants it but you might spare the construction of the path itself

Comment: You can stop redraws on clicks by setting `.allowsHitTesting(false)` on `MyShape`

Comment: it's not drawing anything just processing values which is super fast on the memory stack, the `print` is probably the most intensive thing.

Comment: @Lapieuvre: You see there is a way for stoping the issue!!! It is not just saying "And I don't think you can do anything about it" or talking about "reference type". I hope you and I learned something today!

Comment: Indeed there is a way to limit the redraw on the hit test (that I was not aware of). however this is still recreating the Path at every redraw. and it can be pretty slow. For my test so far it's if you have 1000 points it's like 0.3s but I couldn't yet test with CGPath passed to the shape. BTW you have to stop fixating on "reference type" I didn't say any thing about it here, did you get traumatised? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a `drawingGroup` modifier, SwiftUI doesn't ask for the path again during window resizing (in my testing on macOS 13.5.1).

@vacawama's suggestion of `allowsHitTesting(false)` prevents SwiftUI from asking for the path again when the window is clicked.

If you need to detect clicks on the shape's bounding box, you can do that with an overlay. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {

    ZStack {
      MyShape()
        .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .drawingGroup()
        .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
        .overlay {
          Color.clear
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture { print("tapped!") }
        }
    }
    .padding()
  }
}
```